# Java8 ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm reading a java8 book and come across the difference between `scheduleAtFixedRate` and `scheduleWithFixedDelay` methods from `ScheduledExecutorService`.

I understand the difference between these two methods on the book, however when I tried to write a simple code. It's not so clear why `scheduleAtFixedRate` behaves **synchronously**.

As you can see, I'm allocating 100 threads in the pool. And the scheduler will submit a new task every 1ms, and per task, there's a delay of 1s.

```
    ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    s.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        int num = new Random().nextInt(100);
        System.out.println("Hello World" + num);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished" + num);
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

But why am I getting this output ? A new task will run only after the other.

```
Hello World94
Finished94
Hello World14
Finished14
Hello World90
Finished90
Hello World26
Finished26
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the javadoc for [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then
>     subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently
>     execute.

So do not await for it to execute concurrently, it will always execute sequentially..

Comment: It "may" start late right? if that's the case, then I don't see much difference between scheduleAtFixedRate and scheduleWithFixedDelay methods.

Comment: @RuelosJoel Well, the difference is that `scheduleAtFixedRate` will run at a fixed rate (unless the case you exposed) but `scheduleWithFixedDelay` will *always* have a *fixed* delay between the end of the first runner, and the begin of the second one.